# How to display Python Crash Course Chapter 15 histogram using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

So I am doing problems in the Python Crash Course book and in the end of Chapter 15 'Try it Yourself' section problem 15-10 you are tasked with "Try using a matplotlib to make a die-rolling visualization..." I have all the information laid out and have no errors, but when the program runs the histogram displays the graph and axis, but doesn't display the actual data. Does someone know why this is occurring and what I am missing?

There is a module and class called Die() that initializes and randomly creates rolls. This class and program works perfectly, and is called on in the program below.

## Dice Frequency Histogram Application

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from die import Die

# create two D6 dice
die_1 = Die()
die_2 = Die()

# make some rolls, and store results in a list.
results = []
for roll_num in range(5000):
    result = die_1.roll() + die_2.roll()
    results.append(result)

# analyze the results.
frequencies = []
max_result = die_1.num_sides + die_2.num_sides
for value in range(2, max_result+1):
    frequency = results.count(value)
    frequencies.append(frequency)

plt.bins = []
x_max = die_1.num_sides + die_2.num_sides
for label in range(2, x_max+1):
    plt.bins.append(label)
print(frequencies)
plt.hist(frequencies, plt.bins, histtype = 'bar', facecolor = 'blue')

plt.title("Dice Plot")
plt.xlabel("Results")
plt.ylabel("Frequency of Result")
plt.axis([0,12,0,300])
plt.show()
```

I'm expecting to get a Normal curve model-ish looking set of data. However, I get no data displayed instead. Again, the graph and axis are displayed, but the actual data is not.

Comment: What does `print(results)` give?

Comment: Where you append to `results` is not indented to be in the loop block, so only one result gets appended after the `for roll_num in range(5000):`.

Comment: When I read this it looks like `bins` is supposed to be an integer, not a range?
https://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo.html

Comment: `plt.bins = []` - why are you adding a bins attribute to `plt`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using six sided die and you roll 5000 times, the frequency values are all in the 450 +/- range.  You told `plt.hist` that the bin edges are two through twelve - so all of your bars are off scale on the right of the graph.

There are eleven possible values so tell `.hist` that there are eleven bins.

```
plt.hist(freqs,11)
```

Better yet, you should let `.hist` determine the frequencies - I think this is really what you want.

```
plt.hist(results,11)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you shouldn't try to plot a histogram of already histogrammed values. Instead use the `results` directly. You may adapt the bins as to reflact the fact that the outcomes are discrete in nature.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Die():
    num_sides=6
    def roll(self):
        return np.random.randint(1,self.num_sides+1)

# create two D6 dice
die_1 = Die()
die_2 = Die()

# make some rolls, and store results in a list.
results = []
for roll_num in range(5000):
 result = die_1.roll() + die_2.roll()
 results.append(result)

# analyze the results.
frequencies = []
max_result = die_1.num_sides + die_2.num_sides

x_max = die_1.num_sides + die_2.num_sides

plt.hist(results, bins=np.arange(2, max_result+2)-.5, histtype = 'bar', 
         rwidth=0.8, facecolor = 'blue', edgecolor="k")

plt.title("Dice Plot")
plt.xlabel("Results")
plt.ylabel("Frequency of Result")

plt.show()
```

[image]